# How to disable selected dates on calendar control?

Tags: asp.net, calendar-control

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
```

// How to disable selected dates on Calendar1?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read the faq. http://stackoverflow.com/faq Tell us what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

This is your working code? 
I cannot see any date selected, you have to use the SelectedDates property of the control.

Here is one good reference from W3: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_calendar.asp